# Is there a place / way to automatically mount an NFS share at boot that is not fstab?

Tags: automounting

I have an NFS share that I want to mount at boot, but cannot mount from fstab because it appears to cause blocking boot problems (centOS 7) (not yet sure exactly why, all I know is that rooting in in emergency mode and commenting out the mounting line in `/etc/fstab` file fixes the problem (still debugging)).

Is there any other location that I can specify a share to automatiaclly mount that gets loaded at a later time in the boot sequence than `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: You can use a cronjob but it would be better to find out exactly what the problem is when it's in `/etc/fstab`. Have you checked the boot log or `/var/log/messages/ to see what's happening? Add the particular line in `/etc/fstab` to your question.

Comment: You could write a `systemd` service that executes the mount.

Comment: @NasirRiley Found that the /etc/fstab file was not filled in correctly for the affected share (was not including the column values beyond filesystem and mountpoint), but was still curious about alternative mounting options for future reference.

Comment: If that's what it was then that's the solution. As I started before, you can use a cronjob but that's complicating things where it isn't necessary. You want to mount at boot and that's what `/etc/fstab` is for.